# bnd - Make resulted MANIFEST.MF to have one line per Bundle-ClassPath and RequireBundle entries

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

With OSGi tool bnd

If `bnd.bnd` file has

```
-buildpath: mod.base,\
    mod.common,\
    ...
```

those lines will be as one-liner, though wrapped at 72 potion.
That make output harder to read.

```
Require-Bundle: mod.base,mod.common,...
```

How to tell bdn to make resulted MANIFEST.MF to have one line per Bundle-ClassPath and RequireBundle entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I saw in the source of bnd, it creates a [java.util.jar.Manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html) object. Serializing the content to disk is made with [ManifestUtil](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/aQute.libg/src/aQute/lib/manifest/ManifestUtil.java), because of some limitation with the output of the Manifest class provided by Java.

I use an online tool when when I want to read the OSGi headers: https://robinst.github.io/jar-manifest-formatter/

Although this does not format Require-Bundle, Provide-Capability and Require-Capability headers, I think it should not take more than 10 minutes for you to change the javascript file to format those, too. If you do that, I suggest that you should send a PR for robinst ;).

UPDATE: It can already, thanks to Robin

Comment: I came up with a Java solution to format a Manifest instance to an human readable output: https://gist.github.com/jmini/222e9454667ff0da2e099f05aef0dfa2

Answer (score 3):

The MANIFEST.MF format is defined by the Jar File Specification and it is not intended to be particularly human-readable.

You can format the manifest of any bundle using the `bnd` command. From the command line:

```
bnd print <filename.jar>
```

This will print the imports and exports, as well as the uses constraints, in a nice layout.

By the way... don't use `Require-Bundle`.

Comment: `Require-Bundle` entry is what was generated from bnd.bnd `-buildpath` What is wrong with `Require-Bundle`?

Comment: as of now bnd command line installation is not possible, raised issue https://github.com/bndtools/bnd.manual/issues/33

Comment: Require-Bundle is NOT generated by bnd ... ever

Comment: As Peter says, bnd does not generate `Require-Bundle`. For information on what is wrong with `Require-Bundle`, read the OSGi Core R6 specification, section 3.13.3 "issues with requiring bundles".